# How to add a node as a children to an existing node XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

Here is my code.

```
    XElement Response = new XElement("Response",
                                new XElement("RequestId", requestID),
                                new XElement("ResponseId", "E001"),
                                new XElement("Target", target));
    Response.Add(new XElement("templates"));
```

Now I want to add list of template within templates
How do I do that? I use linq to find  templates.

```
     var t = from e1 in wlnResponse.Elements()
                    where e1.Name.ToString() == "templates"
                    select e1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest storing `templates` `XElement` in a variable before adding it into your document:

```
XElement templates = new XElement("templates");
Response.Add(templates );
```

And then use it to add templates:

```
var t = from e1 in wlnResponse.Elements()
        where e1.Name.ToString() == "templates"
        select e1;

templates.Add(t.ToArray());
```

Comment: Did you mean `templates.Add(t.ToArray());`?

Comment: @svick Sure! Just a typo from previous, `foreach` based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `XElement.Add` method?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx):

> This method adds the new content after the existing content of the XContainer.